# If $A=LL^T$, is $A\otimes I_3 = (L \otimes I_3)(L \otimes I_3)^T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

$A$ is a symmetric positive definite matrix and $LL^T$ its Cholesky factorization.
$A \otimes I_3$ is the Kronecker product of $A$ with the 3x3 identity matrix.

Is the relation $A\otimes I_3 = (L \otimes I_3)(L \otimes I_3)^T$ is true ?

Comment: Why don't you check it on $v \otimes w.$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, I was not aware of the property $(A \otimes B)(C \otimes D) = AC \otimes BD$

I am now able to answer my own question :

$(L \otimes I_3)(L \otimes I_3)^T = (L \otimes I_3)(L^T \otimes I_3^T) = LL^T \otimes I_3I_3^T = A \otimes I_3$